Deduct amount based on priority
I am trying to solve an issue regarding payment. Deduction priority must be based on these orders:

bank_charge = 1.50
profit_amt = 100.00
maintenance = 10.00

User paid amount on 1st cycle = 99.00
System update

bank_charge = 1.50
profit_amt= 97.50

Next cycle, user paid amount = 100.00.
I must first update profit_amt = 100.00 ( add 2.50 only since previous balance 97.50)
then maintenance = 10.00
With balance 87.50.I have to start based on priority again:

bank_charge = 1.50
profit_amt = 100.00
maintenance = 10.00

This is what I have tried so far:
// bank_charge = 1.50
// profit_amt = 100.00
// maintenance = 10.00

$amount = 100.00

foreach ($terms as $term) {
    
            if ($amount >= $term->bank_charge) {

                $term->paid_bank_charge = $term->bank_charge;
                $term->save();
            }else{
                $amount = round($amount, 2);
                if ($amount <= 0) {
                    $amount = 0;
                    break; // Exit the loop
                }else{
                    $term->paid_bank_charge = $amount;
                    $term->save();
                    break; // Exit the loop
                }
            }
            $amount -= $term->bank_charge;

            if ($amount >= $term->profit_amt) {

                $term->paid_profit_amt = $term->profit_amt;
                $term->save();
            }else{
                $amount = round($amount, 2);
                if ($amount <= 0) {
                    $amount = 0;
                    break; // Exit the loop
                }else{
                    $term->paid_profit_amt = $amount;
                    $term->save();
                    break; // Exit the loop
                }
            }
            $amount -= $term->profit_amt;
            
            if ($amount >= $term->maintenance) {

                $term->paid_maintenance = $term->maintenance;
                $term->save();
            }else{
                $amount = round($amount, 2);
                if ($amount <= 0) {
                    $amount = 0;
                    break; // Exit the loop
                }else{
                    $term->paid_maintenance = $amount;
                    $term->save();
                    break; // Exit the loop
                }
            }
            $amount -= $term->maintenance;

            $amount = round($amount, 2);
            if ($amount <= 0) {
                $amount = 0;
                break; // Exit the loop
            }
        }

I have solved deduction based on order. But trouble to start the order if there is excess amount.

trouble to start the order if there is excess amount ....can you be more specific and give an example of the expected output, and the output you're actually getting? It's a bit vague. See also [ask]. Thanks.
